# How to query in linq and check if the passed value is empty

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I want to check if i don't pass value to `request.levelId` and `request.teacherId`
will take all data in table ? (`request.levelId` and `request.teacherId` have data type is int?). Someone help me

```
var query = from ls in _dbContext.GuideLine
                        join lv in _dbContext.Level on ls.LevelId equals lv.Id
                        join tc in _dbContext.Teacher on ls.TeacherId equals tc.Id
                        where ls.LevelId == request.levelId && ls.TeacherId == request.teacherId
                        select new { ls, lv, tc };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the two conditions should be independent of each other, otherwise when one of them(`request.levelId` and `request.teacherId`) is null, the query will return empty.

```
var query = from ls in _dbContext.GuideLine
            join lv in _dbContext.Level on ls.LevelId equals lv.Id
            join tc in _dbContext.Teacher on ls.TeacherId equals tc.Id
            where request.levelId == null || ls.LevelId == request.levelId && request.teacherId == null || ls.TeacherId == request.teacherId
            select new { ls, lv, tc };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var query = from ls in _dbContext.GuideLine
                        join lv in _dbContext.Level on ls.LevelId equals lv.Id
                        join tc in _dbContext.Teacher on ls.TeacherId equals tc.Id
                        where (request.levelId == null && request.teacherId == null) || 
                        (ls.LevelId == request.levelId && ls.TeacherId == request.teacherId) 
                        select new { ls, lv, tc };
```